# The Facebook comment box, does not work correctly with URL Rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, url-rewriting

I would love to use the [Facebook comment plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) in my webpage, but it does not work correctly with [UrlRewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html).

I added the comments code in my webpage (that is generated dynamically and uses Url-Rewriting) and noticed that the comment (that should exist only to the specific page) is visible-available to all the webpages that have the same rewrite rule.

**UPDATE:** The Rewrite rule is

```
<add name="Rule1" virtualUrl="^~/temp/(.*)/(.*).aspx" 
rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
destinationUrl="~/Directory/page.aspx?ItemID=$1&amp;id=$2&amp;lng=gr"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page URL must have a query string that make the URL unique

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID; ?>&amp;xfbml=1"></script>


<fb:comments href="PAGE_URL.'&**uniqueID=uniqueID**" publish_feed="false" num_posts="2" width="430" height="52"></fb:comments>
```

EDIT

You can pass make your URL something like

```
<add name="Rule1" virtualUrl="^~/temp/(.*)/(.*).aspx?data=(.*)" 
rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
destinationUrl="~/Directory/page.aspx?ItemID=$1&amp;id=$2&amp;date=$3&amp;lng=gr"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use correctly that facebook social plugin, you simply need to provide a unique string for each of your pages.

That being said, the URL is not mandatory. If, for example, you have an unique numeric/ alphanumeric/ whatever ID for each page, you could simply have the `href`

```
href="MySiteName+ID"
```

no need to have `href="http://mysitename.com/whateverpage/etc/etc/etc/"`.
In my opinion it's actually better to do it like that because if you're tempted to just dump the URL dynamically, the actual URL might change without your notice, eg.

`http://example.com/pages/about-us` is **A DIFFERENT URL** from `http://example.com/pages/about-us?comment=43&page=4` and, in consequence, shall have a different Comment Feed from facebook. ( aka comments where `href="pages/about-us"` won't be related to comments where `href="pages/about-us?comment=43&page=4"` )